# Could a page with little meaningful content hurt the SEO and rankings of other more important pages of my website?

Tags: seo, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, google-index, ranking

I have a blog and affiliate links website. I have lots of posts with niche content and some posts with product reviews. And that's my main source of traffic: search engine results that are shown to users interested in my posts' content.

Now I've created a new page `/products`. In that page, you'll basically find a grid with product cards and filters to explore and select a product that you like. That page doesn't have any meaningful content, other than the product cards, thumbnails and links (affiliate links). It's not a spam page by any means, it's just a page showing 12 products (per page) with little text content (basically only product titles and affiliate buttons).

That page makes sense only for users that have been reading through my posts, enjoyed the content and would like to see all my product recommendations in a single page. It really does not make sense for a user to land on that page.

I don't think that that page is gonna attract a lot of traffic, and I don't really ***need*** it to be indexed on Google. It is being indexed at this moment, simply by that fact that I'm not blocking it from being index.

But then I thought: given the fact that that page does not have any meaningful content, could the merely presence of that page on my website's Google Search index hurt the SEO ranking of my other pages that I really need to rank well? Should I block that page from being indexed for that reason? Or I can rest assured that even though that specific page won't rank well (for obvious reasons), it will not hurt the performance of my other pages?

I'd still keep that `/products` page available for users that land on my site through one of my posts, and would like to visit my products page after reading one of my posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly sure yoy can just ignore its affect on Google. There is a concept of DA - domain authority and PA - page authority. The page autthority **for this page** will be very low, but if the page is just uninteresting (as opposed to malicious/unrelated to the site) I would expect it to have no effect on the wider site ranking.

Comment: I agree.  A large number of poor quality pages could hurt the entire site, but a single page isn't going to hurt anything.   Even if the a quarter of the pages are poor quality, the whole site is probably going to be able to do fine for SEO.